# Como utilizar um arquivo de extensao .php em um form Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel

Estou com um arquivo `.php` que foi desenvolvido em `php` **puro** e preciso utiliza-lo em `Laravel`.

Para isso preciso chamar ele diretamente do `action` de um `form`, porém a aplicação está sendo desenvolvida em `Laravel`.

Como é possivel utilizar esse arquivo sem utilizar as rotas do `Laravel`?

Comment: Basta jogar dentro da pasta `public/` e então apontar no action como se o public fosse o "root"

Comment: Caro, o que esse arquivo `.php` puro faz? você tem como disponibilizar esse arquivo `php` puro? Não coloque nada na pasta `public´ isso caracteriza falha de segurança, porque, o arquivo vai ficar exposto e irrestrito a todos ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O ideal seria você usar as rotas do laravel para fazer isso, senão não faria sentido você usar um framework que te disponibiliza vários recursos se você não quer usar esses recursos.

Você fazer o seguinte:

Criar um controller na sua aplicação e colocar o seu script php em um método desse controller, criar uma rota e apontar para esse método. Ou se preferir pode jogar o código direto em uma função anônima no arquivo de rotas.

Então no action do seu form você pode apontar para essa rota.

Comment: Más e por exemplo eu preciso importar uma classe feita em php puro para gerar um numero por extenso como eu faço?